# What is the procedures to insert multiple checkbox values to a single column in database using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox

Hi all i am newbie for Codeigniter framework. I would handle medicine prescription module in hospital management system. So there is one multiple checkbox field in prescription add form, and that contains values of Morning,Afternoon,Night. So i had a little confusion to how to create Controller,Model and View.

I cannot understand the array concept when store the values to database. So i can develop the checkbox to store values separately. But there is another issue found in that way, if i want to edit the checkbox value in edit page, the checkboxes are not checked when i am editing the form in edit page.

So i want to store the values in one column and display the checkboxes are checked when i am in edit page. ie). If i checked the Morning and Night checkbox, in database it stores Morning,Night. And edit page also checked the two checkboxes.

I could see many example doubts like as mine in our community, but i cannot clear my issue. So kindly give a right way for solve my issue.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="timings" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Timings<i class="text-danger">*</i></label>                                        
<label><input type="checkbox" name="mor" id="time"   value="Morning"/> Morning</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="aftr"id="time"   value="Afternoon"/> Afternoon</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="nit" id="time"   value="Night"/> Night</label>
</div>
```

Here is my Model:

```
private $table = "prescription";

public function create($data = [])
{    
     return $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
}
```

And my Controller:

form validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mor', 'Morning', '');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('aftr','Afternoon','');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nit','Night','');
```

and Create prescription is:

```
if ($this->input->post('id',true) == null) {
$data['prescription'] = (object)$postData = [
'id'           => $this->input->post('id',true),
'mor'    => $this->input->post('mor',true),
'aftr'    => $this->input->post('aftr',true),
'nit'    => $this->input->post('nit',true),
];
```

and Update is:

```
 else { // update prescription
    $data['prescription'] = (object)$postData = [
    'id'           => $this->input->post('id',true),
    'mor'    => $this->input->post('mor',true),
    'aftr'    => $this->input->post('aftr',true),
    'nit'    => $this->input->post('nit',true),
];
```

Thank you.

Comment: how does your table prescription look like ?
if you want a comma separated string - your arrays doesn't make any sense - so pls show you table structure

Comment: comma separated string also fine. I want if we choose afternoon and night checkbox it will shown in db as Afternoon,Night.                                                                             my table structure is "prescription" as table and "timings" is a column.